# Fonts broken in Chrome and Firefox but works good in Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I have a website, in which the fonts are appearing good in safari, but broken in Chrome and Firefox. I couldn't find which rule is overriding my font settings. Please help.

[image]
This page is live at http://alterknitnewyork.com/drop-off/

In safari, it is taking the settings from `uaf.css` but in chrome and firefox they are scored-out. I have no idea why it is broken. Even I tried to apply the font inline with `!important` tag, but no success.

Comment: You are required to post the minimal, relevant code that shows the problem here. Pointing to your site, which can change or disappear tomorrow, helps no one in the future.

Comment: The issue here is @Rob, I cannot find the relevant part code which is causing the broken fonts.

Comment: @Paran0a Using the web inspector on chrome, can someone analyse what is wrong with my fonts? It is working on safari but not on chrome.!!

Comment: @Paran0a In the screenshot, there is a font scored out in rules of `p`. It should not be scored out, instead it should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have two `@font-face` declarations for the "same" font. One is in `MyFontsWebfontsKit.css` which references a font as *"Elizabeth-Italic"*. The other declaration, in `uaf.css` is referencing a font as *"Elizabeth Italic"*. These are **two distinctly different fonts**.

Assuming you want the italicized font, just set the `font-family` to "Elizabeth-Italic" and you should be good to go.

I'd recommend removing any of the CSS files you don't need (particularly `@font-face` declarations), it will lessen the number of HTTP requests and make the site a bit snappier overall.